# Selenium driver can't click a button no matter what option I use

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am writing a code that scrapes this site: [QBCC](https://my.qbcc.qld.gov.au/myQBCC/s/findlocalcontractor)

You have two dropdown menus and one input field. I have managed the dropdowns but I am having difficulty's with the input field. Its HTML tag looks like this:

```
<input lwc-enmikoh2qu="" class="slds-input" aria-errormessage="help-message-54" id="input-54" name="find" part="input" placeholder="Type suburb, post code here..." type="text"
```

I have tried the following:

- finding it by ID, but it changes every so often (returns button not found)
- by CLASS NAME, by NAME, by CSS SELECTOR, by XPATH, by TAG NAME (returns button not found)
- using JavaScript (returns None, and I can't click it or send keys)
- waiting implicitly and explicitly for the element to load (returns button not found)

Here is the last code I tried for it, one is by CSS SELECTOR and the commented one is by JavaScript:

```
location = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[class*="slds-input"]')))
#location = driver.execute_script('return document.querySelector(\'input[placeholder="Type suburb, post code here..."]\');')
location.click()
location.send_keys('New Auckland')
location.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

And here is the full code (if needed):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

URL = "https://my.qbcc.qld.gov.au/myQBCC/s/findlocalcontractor"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(URL)

time.sleep(8)

industry = Select(driver.find_element(By.ID, '28:2;a'))
industry.select_by_index(4)

range = Select(driver.find_element(By.ID, '46:2;a'))
range.select_by_index(3)

time.sleep(1)

location = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[class*="slds-input"]')))
#location = driver.execute_script('return document.querySelector(\'input[placeholder="Type suburb, post code here..."]\');')
location.click()
location.send_keys('New Auckland')
location.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

time.sleep(3)

page_source = driver.page_source

driver.quit()

soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, "html.parser")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First issue:** is in the below line

```
location = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[class*="slds-input"]')))
```

Change it as below:

```
location = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@part='input-container']//input")))
```

**Second issue:** Below line of code won't work. You need to locate and click on Search button instead.

```
location.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Replace above line with below 2 lines:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='post-code-results']//li//div").click()
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "(//button[@title='Search'])[3]").click()
```

**Full working code:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

URL = "https://my.qbcc.qld.gov.au/myQBCC/s/findlocalcontractor"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(URL)
time.sleep(5)
industry = Select(driver.find_element(By.ID, '28:2;a'))
industry.select_by_index(4)
time.sleep(5)
range = Select(driver.find_element(By.ID, '46:2;a'))
range.select_by_index(3)

location = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@part='input-container']//input")))
location.click()
location.send_keys('New Auckland')
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='post-code-results']//li//div").click()
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "(//button[@title='Search'])[3]").click()
time.sleep(10)
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

- Wait for the Input Field to be Clickable: Instead of using `time.sleep()` to wait for a fixed amount of time, use Selenium's explicit waits to wait for the input field to become clickable before interacting with it. You've already attempted this approach with WebDriverWait, which is the correct approach.
- Verify Iframe or Shadow DOM: Sometimes, input fields can be located within iframes or shadow DOM elements, which may require special handling to access. Ensure that the input field you're trying to interact with is not within an iframe or shadow DOM. If it is, you'll need to switch to that iframe or shadow DOM before interacting with the input field.
- Check for Dynamic Loading: The input field may be dynamically loaded after the initial page load. Verify that the input field is present in the DOM at the time you're trying to interact with it. You can use Selenium's explicit waits to wait for the input field to appear in the DOM before interacting with it.

example:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium import webdriver

URL = "https://my.qbcc.qld.gov.au/myQBCC/s/findlocalcontractor"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(URL)

# Wait for the industry dropdown to be visible and select an option
industry_dropdown = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, '28:2;a')))
industry = Select(industry_dropdown)
industry.select_by_index(4)

# Wait for the range dropdown to be visible and select an option
range_dropdown = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, '46:2;a')))
range_select = Select(range_dropdown)
range_select.select_by_index(3)

# Wait for the location input field to be clickable and interact with it
location_input = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[class*="slds-input"]')))
location_input.click()
location_input.clear()  # Clear any existing text
location_input.send_keys('New Auckland')
location_input.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

# Wait for the page to load after entering the location
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'some_element_on_the_next_page')))

# Continue with the rest of your logic
```